# Problema al calcular varios porcentajes en Java

Tags: java

estoy empezando con Java y estoy atascado con este problema, para el que solo puedo usar bucles For y la clase Math. El problema es que no consigo aumentar la tasa.
Esto es lo que tiene que salir por pantalla:

5 años  250.0(1.0%)     375.0(1.5%)     500.0(2.0%)     625.0(2.5%)
6 años  300.0(1.0%)     450.0(1.5%)     650.0(2.0%)     750.0(2.5%)
7 años  350.0(1.0%)     525.0(1.5%)     700.0(2.0%)     875.0(2.5%)
8 años  400.0(1.0%)     600.0(1.5%)     800.0(2.0%)     1000.0(2.5%)

y esto lo que me sale:

5 años  250.0(1.0%)     250.0(1.5%)     250.0(2.0%)     250.0(2.5%)
6 años  250.0(1.0%)     250.0(1.5%)     250.0(2.0%)     250.0(2.5%)
7 años  250.0(1.0%)     250.0(1.5%)     250.0(2.0%)     250.0(2.5%)
8 años  250.0(1.0%)     250.0(1.5%)     250.0(2.0%)     250.0(2.5%).

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
   double capitalInicial = 5000.0;
   double tasa = 1.0;
   int anios = 5;
   double intereses = capitalInicial * tasa / 100 * anios;
   for(int i = 5; i <= 8; i++) {
   System.out.println(i + " años \t" + intereses + "(1.0%) \t" + intereses + "(1.5%) \t" + intereses + "(2.0%) \t" + intereses + "(2.5%) \t");
```

Os agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: mueve `double intereses = capitalInicial * tasa / 100 * anios;` dentro del for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problema:

Tendrías que mover a `double intereses = capitalInicial * tasa / 100 * anios;` dentro de tu ciclo `for` y reemplazar a `anios` por el iterador del for (**`i`**), ya que `intereses` solo se estaba calculando una vez, es por ello que el mismo resultado se repetía en todas las ocasiones.

##### Solución:

Ahora, para que tengas los mismos resultados que el ejercicio, tendrías que multiplicar a `intereses` por los porcentajes que te solicitan **(1.0%, 1.5%, 2.0%, 2.5%)**. Veamos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double capitalInicial = 5000.0;
    double tasa = 1.0;
    for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i++) {
        double intereses = capitalInicial * tasa / 100 * i;
        System.out.println(i + " anios \t" + intereses*(1.0) + "(1.0%) \t" + intereses*(1.5) + "(1.5%) \t" + intereses*(2.0) + "(2.0%) \t" + intereses*(2.5) + "(2.5%) \t");
    }
}
```

##### Output:

```
// 5 anios    250.0(1.0%)     375.0(1.5%)    500.0(2.0%)    625.0(2.5%)     
// 6 anios    300.0(1.0%)     450.0(1.5%)    600.0(2.0%)    750.0(2.5%)     
// 7 anios    350.0(1.0%)     525.0(1.5%)    700.0(2.0%)    875.0(2.5%)     
// 8 anios    400.0(1.0%)     600.0(1.5%)    800.0(2.0%)    1000.0(2.5%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque `intereses` se calcula solo una vez. Para que cambie cada año debe estar dentro del `for`, y se puede usar el contador `i` como el valor del año:

```
    double capitalInicial = 5000.0;
    double tasa = 1.0;
    for (int i = 5; i <= 8; i++) {
        double intereses = capitalInicial * tasa / 100 * i;
        System.out.println(i + " años \t" + intereses + "(1.0%) \t" + intereses + "(1.5%) \t" + intereses + "(2.0%) \t" + intereses + "(2.5%) \t");
    }
```